# What has been said to be unique to Earth in the Star Trek universe?

Tags: star-trek

This is a staple of sci-fi (probably a trope): some *mundane* thing is declared to be "only found on Earth". I think some foods have been mentioned before as being "unique to Earth as far as we know in the galaxy", but I can't remember what.

Has that ever been mentioned, or am I partially remembering wrong?

EDIT:
I'm **not** asking for a list. A list of all these would definitely be a wrong thing to ask. **Not a list**. Just was that used and an example.

Comment: Are you, ehm... you're not really asking for a list, are you?

Comment: Nope, not a list.

Comment: WOuld a list help?

Comment: I distinctly remember chocolate being mentioned as unique to Earth. However, I remember that from _Farscape_, so it doesn't count.

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoBiochemicalBarriers

Comment: @Richard I'm not asking for a list. And actually, the opposite of that trope.

Comment: Not asking for a list, so you just want one item?

Comment: @phantom42 Yes, one example. A scalar, not a list of 1. :)

Comment: But then when someone comes up with a different answer of one item, you get into the issue of "which one item is more correct than the other". So, this really *does* fall under the list question problem.

Comment: See also: [Are one-sided answerable questions non-constructive?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2968/5184) and [Are questions looking to simply prove or disprove a premise with a yes/no answer a good fit for our site?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1450/5184)

Comment: You may not be asking for a list, but a list is what you'd get.  First one person posts one example, then another person posts another example, and the end result is a list.

Comment: I'm saddened by what this place has turned out to be. It wasn't like that in the beginning. Used to be you could ask questions. Now, if the answer turns out it *could* be a list, it's not valid. /rant

Comment: @MPelletier Maybe you should ask a list of questions... Is paper unique to Earth in the Star Trek universe? Is gold unique to Earth in the Star Trek universe? Is Chocolate unique to Earth in the Star Trek universe? etc... until you find something with the answer 'Yes'.

Comment: Even Shakespeare is not Earth unique as the Klingons claimed him as their own in *Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country*: "You've not experienced Shakespeare until you've read him in the original Klingon."

Comment: I seem to recall there was something unique to Earth, but it was particularly *not* flattering.

Comment: @Michael Go on...

Comment: @MPelletier I don't remember what it was, just that it wasn't particularly flattering.

Answer (score -3):

Humans?  They might be on other planets now, but they all came from Earth originally.

Comment: Nice try :) Even that is a bit thrown off, as a lot of old TOS episodes had something like "very close to human" aliens.